# How to set up a 30fps loop in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, game-loop

I am currently developing a small game/simulation for school in C++ with Qt and I have some background with Java. My question is how to setup a basic gameloop with Qt in an 800/600 window. I tried drawing into a GraphicsView-window with overriding the paintEvent but I can't  set up a loop like that and I have some kind of mistake with overriding it.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "graphicsview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(800, 600);
    setWindowTitle("A* Pathfinder");
    gView = new GraphicsView(this);
    setCentralWidget(gView);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

GraphicsView-class:

```
#include "graphicsView.h"

void GraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawLine(10,10, 100,100);
}
```

graphicsView.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define GRAPHICSVIEW_H

#endif // GRAPHICSVIEW_H
#include <QGraphicsView>

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
  protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
```

Sorry if similar questions got asked already but I am really stuck and can't find help for my specific case. Again, I want an 800x600 window in which I can draw graphics at 30fps.

Comment: Gaming loop timing: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: Please strive to format your code uniformly and take care that indentation is consistent, particularly when you're asking for help. You may not feel it is important, but it definitely is, especially when reading unfamiliar code.

Comment: @dkasak sry formatting and indentation got kinda lost when I copied it

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are heading the wrong direction - you do not need to override `QGraphicsView`, a stock one suffices. You do not need to override the `paintEvent()` - that doesn't do what you think it does. You don't render your scene there, that's the code which renders only the frame for the view - how the empty view looks, not what the view contains.

If you have custom drawing which is not provided by stock graphics items (such as rectangles, text, arcs and whatnot) you need to implement your own `QGraphicsItem` and implement its `paint()` function - that's how it works, every item is responsible for its painting, the scene just manages all items, the view just visualizes the scene.

You definitely don't want a timer firing at a fixed rate, that is a very naive and poor solution. It doesn't account for the time rendering and game logic processing takes, and if you want a steady frame rate, you do need to account for those variables.

30 FPS means you will have to churn out a frame every 33.33 msec. So you need to schedule every subsequent frame based on how long the previous took. For example, if the previous frame took 15 msec, you need to schedule the next in `33.33 - 15` msec, achieving finer grained control and steadier framerate as long as your CPU can keep up.

You can use the static function `QTimer::singleShot()` to schedule every subsequent frame with a custom interval.

Comment: If there's enough time to render and process a frame in the first place a fixed QTimer would be just as fine. QTimer::singleShot() doesn't give you more time per frame. QTimer will fire at 30 fps independent of the time consumed in your routines. You might have to drop frames in both solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't use a continuously firing timer with fixed interval for anything other than a trivial example. It would rely on using a single thread and blocking the main thread, which is not really desired. So as you extend on your engine you will inevitably run into limitations and complications.

Comment: You're right, but a fine-grained control is sometimes a bit hard with Qt. For example QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer gives you just `virtual void render()`, which is hopefully being called at 60 fps :)

Comment: Qt itself has plenty of design limitations and hard coded values someone assumed will work for everyone. For example - you don't have control over the actual rate of event loops. That's a whole different topic :) And sure, if you want to shove your rendering into Qt's existing pipeline, you are stuck with its behavior.